# c# dynamicly adding item in listbox - Items not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to dynamicly add items (textbox and button) into a listbox.

This is my `xaml`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="projects_list" Height="459" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="86" Width="755">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="42">

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And, in the `StackPanel` I want to have my 2 buttons.

Inside a `foreach`, I create the buttons like this:

```
items.ForEach(delegate (Projects project)
{
    Button txt = new Button(); // NAME
    txt.Height = 32;
    txt.Width = 320;
    txt.Content = project.name;

    Button gen_token = new Button(); 
    gen_token.Height = 26;
    gen_token.Width = 180;
    gen_token.Content = "Generate";

    this.projects_list.Items.Add(txt); 
    this.projects_list.Items.Add(gen_token);  
}
```

But, When I add the elements into my `ListBox`, nothing appears.
Even though, there is a good number of `StackPanel`s in my list.

Any idea? 
Thanks!

**EDIT** : 
If I Had

```
      <Button Content="{Binding}" ></Button>
```

Into the `stackPanel`, My buttons are showing, but not really has I want to, they are one by `stackpanel` and I want both buttons on every panel ..

**EDIT 2 :**
So, I tried this :

```
        public List<Dictionary<string, Button>> Items { get; set; }
        ....
        Items = new List<Dictionary<string, Button>>();
        DataContext = this;
```

And later in the `each`

```
         Dictionary<string, Button> dict = new Dictionary<string, Button>() { { "name", txt }, { "token", gen_token } };
                Items.Add(dict);
```

So In my xaml, I have :

```
            <ListBox x:Name="projects_list" Height="459" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="86" Width="755" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="42">
                        <Button Content="{Binding Path=name}" ></Button>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Path=token}" ></Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

But still, nothing appears :(

Comment: You're specifying each item to visually be an empty stackpanel.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using MVVM and binding to generate the items dynamically?

Comment: Hum, I've tried to use the binding but It never showed.
Actually I want to create the button inside my class because theres is more of action not showed in this example.
How Can I tell the stackpanel to create my 2 buttons ?

Comment: You're doing it all wrong, you never crate visual elements in code with WPF...

Comment: To make it more clear what chris said above: when you are specifying the ItemTemplate you declare how each item should be represented: by an empty stackpanel. So when you add the buttons they will be represented as stackpanels, where the datacontext of the stackpanel is the actual button. That's why you see a big bunch of stackpanels appearing. 
To resolve it add the buttons to the datatemplate in xaml and bind the ItemsSource to a collection in the code behind or in a viewmodel.

Comment: I've edit, my post, this time what I've done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick example:

Window.Xaml

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Item 1", "Item2" };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

This is just a quick example to give you an idea. You would probably do a ViewModel instead of code behind.